# Set up kismatic in local machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I'm going to install kubernetes cluster using kismatic, using 2 aws ec2 instances as per the below doc.

https://github.com/apprenda/kismatic/blob/master/docs/intent.md

Im getting below error when executing, "./kismatic install apply"

- Etcd nodes: Node #1: Invalid IP provided
  error validating plan: Plan file validation error prevents installation from proceeding

All the services are going to be installed in one istance, therefore im using private IP.

Comment: In the beginning, you mention 2 AWS instances but in end you say - all services will be installed on one instance. Irrespective - you will have to use a publically reachable IP address to be able to apply Kismatic playbooks.

Comment: It means one ec2 instance for execute "./kismatic install apply" command and the other one as a node.

Comment: I would suggest use `--verbose` with that command paste output here.

Comment: kismaticuser@kismatic-server:~$ ./kismatic install apply --verbose

Validating==========================================================================
Reading installation plan file "kismatic-cluster.yaml"                          [OK]
Validating installation plan file                                               [OK]
Validating SSH connectivity to nodes                                            [OK]
error validating plan: error creating ansible runner: Could not find 'python' in the PATH. Ensure that python 2.7 is installed and in the path as 'python'.

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory- you need to install python 2.7 on the instance from which you are running kismatic